# Where do I put DESC in a mysql query? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, syntax

This is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY 'timestamp' LIMIT $startAt, $perPage";
```

I'm trying to sort the results by the latest (latest on top), so I tried to add DESC.
But where ever I put it in the query it gives me an error, the only way it doesn't give an error is like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY 'timestamp' DESC  LIMIT $startAt, $perPage";
```

But even though it doesn't give an error, it still doesn't work.

This probably seems like a silly thing to ask but it's really driving me crazy

Comment: Remove the quotes from timestamp. And do a bit more research if you want presents :3 (Also yadda yadda I hope you;re escaping those variables and not using `mysql_query`)

Comment: Add sample data and desired output. Because the syntax is right. What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp is the datatype in MySQL. So, always try to avoid such column name in your table. Even, if you have a column named as timestamp, you must have to use backtick. So, use below query:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `timestamp` LIMIT $startAt, $perPage";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try backtick on timestamp :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC  LIMIT $startAt, $perPage";
```

Using backticks permits you to use alternative characters

I think however, instead of mandating whether or not you can use backticks, they should have a standard for names. It solves more 'real' problems.

Comment: Would be worth editing your answer to explain why the backtick is necessary. Many users fail to learn the differences

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia: it is not backtick it is single quote

Answer (score 0):

Do not use quote in field name. Try this:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY timestamp DESC  LIMIT $startAt, $perPage";
```

Comment: @Ayoub: did you try this?